# How can I enumerate threads I created in my .NET project?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, multithreading

I need to enumerate all my threads in a for each loop, so I can examine the name of each one, and execute code conditionally if a specific name of a thread exists.

Can you enumerate your threads without creating a collection specifically maintaining your threads?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate process threads using `Process.Threads` however these aren't directly the same as the managed threads you use.

If you want to keep track of your managed threads you're best adding them and removing them from your own concurrent list when they're created and when they finished, although you seem to want to avoid that. You could create your own Thread class derivative that wraps this for you.